# Why jQuery doing unwanted multiple actions of single command?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i resize browser the it gives multiple alerts. I used "return false" not working.

If I used unbind()/unbind('resize') then it works but it creates an other problem- the resize() function stops working from second time browser/window resize.

My code-

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    alert($(".myclass").parent().width());

    $(window).bind('resize',function() {
        alert($(".myclass").parent().width());
    });

});
</script>
<section class="myclass"></section>
```

Comment: How are you even debugging this? So many alerts! Use `console.log` instead.

Comment: use console.log to catch these type of events. doing alert is a bit annoying in this case. Use firebug or the developer tool in IE (F12).

Comment: These are not a solution, these are avoiding the problem. 
I am looking only a single javascript/jquery command not any kind of logic, which will stop multiple actions without harming the window resize() function.

Answer (score 0):

Because the resize triggers everytime the browser changes.

If you are resizing 100 pixels it can trigger up to 100 times.

Something like this should work and trigger only once you stopped resizing the window:

```
var resizing = false, stopedResizing = true;
$(window).bind('resize',function() {
    if(!resizing){
        console.log("started resizing. Width = " + $(".myclass").parent().width());
        resizing = true;
    }
    stopedResizing = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
       if(!stopedResizing){
           stopedResizing = true;
           setTimeout(function(){
               if(stopedResizing && resizing){
                resizing = false;
                console.log('Stoped resizing. Width = ' + $(".myclass").parent().width());
               }
           }, 500);
       }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Why not console.log ? This alert will stack up. Annoying.

Comment: These are not a solution, these are avoiding the problem. 
I am looking only a single javascript/jquery command not any kind of logic, which will stop multiple actions without harming the window resize() function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with jQuery, but on the browser's implementation of resize.

Depending which browser you use it may trigger intermediate resizes, or a resize when your mouse is released only.

Comment: These are not a solution, these are avoiding the problem. 
I am looking only a single javascript/jquery command not any kind of logic, which will stop multiple actions without harming the window resize() function.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    alert($(".myclass").parent().width());
    var lastTime = 0;

    $(window).bind('resize',function() {
        var currentTime = new Date().time();
        if(currentTime > lastTime + 5000)
            alert($(".myclass").parent().width());
        lastTime = currentTime;
    });

});
```

...so that it will only fire on resizes at least 5 seconds apart. Normally though, you'd want to act when resizing stops, not when it starts.

Comment: These are not a solution, these are avoiding the problem. 
I am looking only a single javascript/jquery command not any kind of logic, which will stop multiple actions without harming the window resize() function.

Comment: @JonakirGhum The kind of solution you're after does not exist. The best you can do is avoid the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This code fires ones on mouseover of the window after the a resize event as occurred.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var windowResized = false;

        function callFunction() {

            console.log("I am called once after window resize");
        }


        $(window).mouseover(function() {

            if (windowResized == true) {

                callFunction();
                windowResized = false;
            }

        })

        $(window).resize(function() {

            windowResized = true;

        });

    })
```

Comment: Wow .. still looking at it and already voted down. Nothing wrong here though.

Comment: These are not a solution, these are avoiding the problem. 
I am looking only a single javascript/jquery command not any kind of logic, which will stop multiple actions without harming the window resize() function.

Comment: @Jonakr Ghum - They are "help" and that was this is about. People come here to get some help to move forward. As such it is not the intention to offer a ready made code replacement.
The reason your code is not working is because the logic is wrong. Code examples will help you to think for yourself to find the problem.

Comment: Okay Danien, I am wrong but Mozilla Developer example? Kindly see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onresize . Please kindly dont say they they are wrong.

Comment: @Jonakr Ghum - I am not saying they are wrong, yet that example is not based on jQuery. 
For teh jquery version look here: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: @Jonakr Ghum - I have adjusted the code in my example to a fully fuctional logic. If you like it, please mark it as the answer.